# Is it still possible to edit a document in google docs from alfresco share 4.2?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a 4.0.x binary installation of alfresco and have this menu highlighted below:
[image: google docs edit menu option]

I have 2 custom installed 4.2.c versions and this option is missing. I have done the following to try and enable it as read from different parts of the web:

1) added the two following lines to both the share and the repo's alfresco-global.properties file
**#enable GoogleDocs integration

googledocs.enabled=true

googledocs.googleeditable.enabled=true**


2)Modified the share-custom-config.xml file in attempts to enable this and other google docs functionality. 

So far this is the only thing missing. I am not sure whether this is a bug or whether I'm overlooking something else.

Comment: Did you apply the Google Docs amp? (IIRC, it's an optional add-in)

Comment: Yes I have just applied the latest amps and nothing works

Comment: Did you apply the Repo AMP to the Repo war, Share AMP to the Share war, then follow the [Enabling Google Docs integration documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fat-adminconsole-googledocs.html)?

Comment: Yes except I use the community edition so that link doesn't apply to it. I checked the extension is enabled in the properties file in the subsystem folder, and checked that the right mime-type is defined in context file also.

Comment: The process for setting it up on community should be almost identical to enterprise, so that link ought to still largely cover you

Comment: Which version of the Google Docs integration did you install? If you run `java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar list tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war` and `java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar list tomcat/webapps/share.war` then what output do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google Docs integration works fine with Alfresco Community Edition 4.2.c. In fact, here is a video that shows you how to get it working:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbNDEp1KG1g

The video shows that the out-of-the-box installer will not create a working Google Docs integration due to changes on the Google side. So you need to reinstall the AMPs to both the alfresco and share wars as gagravarr mentioned above.

If you are using Google Docs integration in the repository folders (external to a Share site) you will need to install from head because there is a bug. If you are using the integration only within Share sites the latest released version of the integration, downloadable from the [4.2.c file list page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_4.2.c), will be fine.